# Fluent animated image working as a background?

Tags: html, image, animation

I have a very specific client. He requied creation of a loading image. But no simple spinnig wheels or whatnot. It's his product spinning. The problem is - when I created a gif with ten frames, it's choppy and not very fluent.

What other format can I use, that will work on the web as a background for page loading?

Comment: Adobe Flash! =) Users would just LOVE the website loading huge smooth cool swirly blinking animation to show it's loading something!

Comment: Haha, yeah, my client showed me a site built with Flash. Unfortunately, it is obsolete and not working for backgrounds.

Comment: You mean really **background**? I'm afraid any option will be slow. Rotating an HTML image in the background would probably be slow as hell and highy depend on the browser, OS and hardware. GIF is as fast and reliable as it can get. If you don't care about bandwidth, you can try increasing number of frames and adjusting framerate. But I wouldn't expect much. AFAIK, flash can be used in the background actually, you can try googling for it. But in this mode even flash would be slow...

Comment: I did search for swf in background option, but the only way is to place a div positioned in the middle. Placing even more frames in the gif woudn't help, since the stroke of the image still would be choppy. I need something like animated PNGs, haha :)

Comment: It sounds like you want a better tool for making animated gifs. The image looks choppy only because whatever you used to rotate the image made it choppy.

Comment: It needs to be transparent. GIF doesn't support partial transparency, so any soft edges are being sharpened.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by rotate and the browsers in which you want it to work, you might be able to get away with (almost) pure CSS.

```
#animated {animation: loading 5s infinite linear}
@keyframes loading {
  from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to   {transform: rotate(359deg);}
}

<img id="animated" src="logo.png">
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes#Browser_Compatibility) has more info on support and what versions require prefixes.

Comment: It rotates from left to right (it's a cube) so I need couple of frames.

Comment: In that case you could just flip 0 and 359 degrees around.

Comment: Imagine a cube with four different sides. How can I flip 2D image to show the side that is hidden at the beginning?

Comment: I see. The most obvious solution would probably be APNG, but unfortunately that's only supported in Gecko and Presto. To switch between multiple PNG images you could use the aforementioned @keyframes, SVG, or JS, but none of those solutions seem very elegant.